# Forgot mongodb admin database credentials. Reset everything

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, replication, sharding

I forgot the credentials of my admin user.
Hence i am not able to connect to cluster mongo shell. 
Now i want to delete all users and and credentials or even if reset of mongodb is possible then it will be a lot help.

I tried following commands but got "authentication required error".
db.createUser(), db.dropDatabase().

I expect to create new admin user with credentials.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by logging in to your Atlas Cluster here: https://www.mongodb.com. Then, on the left sidebar, you click on 'Database Access'. There you can manage the users and you can even delete them and create new ones.

Comment: Thanks. But i want to create a admin user on my local mongodb environment.

Comment: Well, the thing is that you need to be connected with an admin user from your local environment to be able to create an admin user.

Comment: Is there any way to reset everything in cluster and setup everything new??

Comment: Yes, you can everything you want with your cluster by looging in to it on the web as i said. Go to [Mongo DB](https://www.mongodb.com) and on the upper right side click 'Sign In'.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem still exists.